# TableView not synced

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

method, `row` sometimes is larger than the size of my array. This is **VERY** weird, because I also have

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
```

implemented to return my arrays count.

I was under the impression that whenever the `TableView` calls

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

, it would also call `numberOfRows`, so `row` would never be larger than `numberOfRows`.

Comment: Not familiar with `NSTableView` but I would assume so. The problem is maybe somewhere else

Comment: It's better if you show real code rather than describing what you believe it does.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTableView` calls `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` but not `numberOfRows(in:)` when it needs a cell view for display, which can be very often when scrolling. Call `reloadData()` or insert/remove rows when the number of rows changes.